# Capacity planning and modelling

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling

I have a business case in which I am going to model how many devices are required given the predicted workload in a series of monthly cohorts in the next ten years.

The work could come from multiple service lines and there are multiple options for doing each specific type of work. We are going to find out the minimum capacity required to finish the workload at each month. The modelling outcome should be an estimated capacity required for each year that can cover the demand in any possible scenario.

What kind of model or methodology can I use for this modelling task?

Comment: Maybe search for network calculus?

Comment: Thanks @DanielS for sharing your idea. Network calculus is typically used for computer system queueing problem. My work is for healthcare service, I will do a research to see if I can properly use network calculus in my use case.